# Font losing weight after capture using PhantomJS

Tags: css, phantomjs

Using PhantomJS 1.9.7
Centos 6.5
All packages required are installed.

Using the rasterize.js example from the PhantomJS site. For the most part, the capture looks good, aside from the fact that the font-weight is not right. See example.

http://cl.ly/image/223i0b1x2E1g

I have tried using different fonts and playing with the CSS. I have compiled my own version of PhantomJS as well, just to see.

Here is the current CSS for the example.

```
.example-for-se {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: 900;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 2rem;
margin: 0 0 0.25rem 0;
}
```

I am doing everything locally. The Centos system is on my MAC as a VirtualBox and I am working with a static file.

So the command looks like this.

> phantomjs rasterize.js example.html example.png

Any ideas?

Comment: Kerning looks weird too. Is the screencap on the left also from CentOS?

Comment: You are right, kerning is off. Yes, screencap on the left is also the page being served from CentOS.

Comment: Does it look right when captured on the MAC?

Comment: Captured on the MAC? Do you mean running MAMP with PhantomJS installed on the MAC? I have not tried that. This needs to run on Centos or Ubuntu. I have tried it on Ubuntu as well.

Comment: I mean that it might be an installed fonts issue. The CentOS might be lacking the bold font, which another system might have.